# Receiving net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH error in android webView

Tags: android, https, android-webview

I'm trying to load a URL to a webView, but Some time I'm Receiving net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH error in onReceivedError method and the page stopped loading.

The URL is one time generated by the backend and has a lot of redirection.

my webViewClinet :

```
private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error) {
            super.onReceivedError(view, request, error);
            ToastUtil.showToast(error, getContext());

        }
```

Can anyone help me?